# Sound meter to measure Sound Pressure Level

Tags: android, audio

I am using `MediaRecorder` to try to create a sound meter which returns the Sound Pressure Level (what I believe most people mean when they refer to everyday volume in decibels).

Currently, I am using this implementation to get values in decibels:

`return 20.0 * Math.log10(Math.abs(mMediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()) / 32768)`

I'm not sure if this is correct. Sitting in a room with no noise other than a fan, it is returning values anywhere between -30 and -20. If I speak near the microphone, it jumps to values near -0.5 or so.

Reading many answers on this website, it seems that is is difficult and largely unreliable to measure SPL without calibrated devices. However, I don't need highly accurate results, only results applicable to everyday curiousity and non-extreme situations.

There are apps such as [Sensor Box for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.androidsensorbox&hl=en), which seem to return decent results with no calibration needed to start. Using it in the same room, it is returning results between 40-60dB, and when I speak it jumps into the 80-90dB range.

How can I duplicate these results? Thank you!

Comment: You say you don't need accurate results, but how accurate?  In what way would a meaningless number inform your curiosity?  It seems that the results for your demo app are way off too. For example, see the low dBSPL values here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Examples_of_sound_pressure  The thing to note with your sample app is that they only claim information about "intensity changes", and for that, calibration doesn't matter too much, and my guess is they only report "dB" not "dBSPL".

Comment: I suppose what I mean by not needing highly accurate results is that I would like the app to perform similar to any simple sound meter someone would pick up at a store for $10-15. Nothing high-end and highly precise, but not random either.

Comment: BTW, on the Sensor box returning "decent" results-  a quick look up says 80-90 is way high for speech.  80-90 is hearing damage range over the long term, its equivalent to a heavily trafficed road.  Remember being off by 1 dB is logarithmic, so it doesn't mean slightly more, it means an order of magnitude more noise.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Examples_of_sound_pressure

Comment: Ideally as accurate as possible using only the phone's standard microphone. I just mean not as accurate as an expensive sound meter an audio professional might use.

Comment: I think you're both right on the inaccuracy of the Sensor Box app, because it consistently returns a measure of ~80-90 dB when I speak near the phone in a regular voice.

Comment: The 80-90 dB might be reasonable since it seems like you're speaking "near the phone", so the number is hard to guess.  Try putting it a meter away.  It's more the quite fan which made me think it was off.

Comment: @tom10 With the fan off, it actually now returns values in the 20-30dB range and speaking with the phone at arm's length returns values between 50-70dB. That seems more in line with the Wiki tables.

Comment: I don't think there's any magic here, and I suspect that they just guessed a baseline by a bit of trial and error, in anything.  And do they or you turn off automatic gain control?  So even if you could calibrate it, that would change with AGC.  I see what you want to do, but in the end you're too limited by hardware to make any more than a crude guess for your baseline, and you'll be lucky to be within 30dB, which is entirely useless even for "everyday curiosity" as it's less informative than showing the message "does this sound loud, then it's >70dBSPL" as your only "reading".

Comment: I'm not sure if they turn off automatic gain control. There is no input requested from me, and they don't mention whether or not they turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that decibels isn't an exact measurement-  its a signal to noise ratio.  You need a base measurement and need to measure the ratio of the amplitude of your signal to that baseline noise.  Amplitude alone is meaningless.

Your second problem-  where did you get 32768 from?  The formula should be `20.0 * Math.log10(Math.abs(signal/baseline))`.

Comment: I used 32,768 because reading many other questions, it seemed that `getMaxAmplitude()` returns unsigned 16-bit integer values and dividing by 32,767 or 32,768 was recommended in many of the answers to normalize the returned values. I'm not sure if this is correct, and the developer guides are unclear.

What are you using for `baseline`? Some answers mention that it might be more appropriate to have produce some baseline tone and use that to measure against/cancel out ambient noise, but I'm not sure how to do that. The Sensor Box app I linked also requires no calibration to start up.

Comment: I have no idea what some random app is doing, but if its claiming to read decibels and not calibrating, its just making up numbers.  You *can't* measure decibels without a baseline-  its a physics impossibility.  If they're using a hardcoded baseline value its just going to be very wrong on most devices.

Comment: As for what baseline should be-  the value of getMaxAmplitude in the room when silent would be good.

Comment: Suppose the user starts the sound meter in an already noisy room. How would I get the baseline in that situation?

Comment: Capture the baseline beforehand and use it later would be my best suggestion.

Comment: I added some lines to have the very first value returned from `getMaxAmplitude()` to be the baseline, but now it is returning `Infinity` no matter what sounds at present afterward.

Comment: "the maximum absolute amplitude measured since the last call, or 0 when called for the first time"  The first time always returns 0.  That would make the result of division infinity.  Do it from the second reading instead.

Comment: In what way is the "the room when silent" good?  Also, with AGC, isn't calibration meaningless anyway?